# ios 9 screen size and points vs pixels

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios9

I have an app that was written in ios 7 that I ported to ios 9.  Somehow a lot of the width's of things got smaller. Did the points or pixels or screen size settings change?

I normally set frames of things like so:

```
CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 340);
```

But if I wanted say the width to be half the screen I should do something like so, correct:

```
float width = self.view.frame.size.width / 2; // as long as view is full screen
CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, width);
```

Is this the correct approach?  I wonder why my old app shrunk certain things too. Thanks.

Comment: The screen sizes didn't get smaller for the same device, did you change to the 600x600 storyboards?  Are you comparing the same devices?

Comment: Yeah I am on the same device. I just did everything programmatically without storyboards as I wanted to learn the code/sdk. All I did was update ios 9 on device and xcode to 7 and running ios 9 sdks.

Comment: I'm also still cleaning deprecated stuff too.

Comment: better to use auto layout for this kind of use

Comment: How does auto layout work without storyboards? I want to learn programmatically